# Print Javascript function in htm php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

this  is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#input').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
            $('.log').html('Card type: ' + (result.card_type == null ? '-' : result.card_type.name)
                     + '<br>Valid: ' + result.valid
                     + '<br>Length valid: ' + result.length_valid
                     + '<br>Luhn valid: ' + result.luhn_valid);
        });
    });
</script>
```

i m print the result value in html tag like:

```
<h1><script>document.write(result.card_type.name())</script></h1>



<h1><script>document.write(result.valid())</script></h1>



<h1><script>document.write(result.length_valid())</script></h1>



<h1><script>document.write(result.luhn_valid())</script></h1>
```

bt its not showing the value..!!

Comment: instead of using `document.write` use jquery's `.html()` or `.text()` instead

Comment: i want to print "result.length_valid" in between html tag..!!

Comment: then concatenate it between the html tag..!!

Comment: bt how to concatenate??

Comment: any1 knows how to print result value in html tag??

Answer (score 0):

The "result" variable is local to that function.  You cant use it in the document like that.

Delete those 4 lines in your HTML and just add this instead:

```
<h1 class="log"></h1>
```

Do you get the desired result?  If not you'll need to better explain what "validateCreditCard" is.